# Active Directory: The Principal Class - S.DS.AM vs S.DS.AD

Tags: c#, sql-server, active-directory, ldap

I am working on an access audit report for Active Directory. I am extracting data via a C# script component in SSIS, using LDAP, into a SQL Server database. This is my first major foray into AD, so I freely admit a lack of intimate knowledge. I am trying to remove the blinders by asking those with experience on the topic. Pardon me in advance if I have mixed any of my metaphors.

With respect to retrieving data for all users, is it best just to stick with the Principal Class, and access GroupPrincipal, UserPrincipal, and ComputerPrincipal (i.e. concrete classes) via S.DS.AM, or is it better to get everything from S.DS.AD (see reference below)? I understand that both are subclassed off S.DS, so it is possible to miss objects not contained in the from S.DS.AD when using S.DS.AM. Is there any pertinent data or objects that is contained in S.DS.AD, but not in S.DS.AM, that would be helpful for an access control audit? Also, I understand that if PageSize=1000 then I may need to go with S.DS.AD and then loop through S.DS.AM.

If it is best to use S.DS.AM, is there a way to capture any abstract or auxillary classes that have been created and are sub-classed off of the concrete classes? Would I just use StructuralObjectClass property value?

**S.DS.AD:**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory(v=vs.110).aspx

**S.DS.AM:**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: IMHO, the requirement is the source of selection criteria. There are many things which are not possible solely through AccountManagement, where ActiveDirectory assembly helps(already mentioned in your question). I'd suggest you to limit the scope of your question, and ask as to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The problem is that there is no scope requirement - the firm just wants to audit access and has left me to figure it out. So, it can be either very big in scope or very narrow. Since I have room to figure it out, I am trying to include items that may be needed in the future so I can avoid future development efforts and use data that is already provided while being mindful of potential performance issues. As a result, I am trying to see what is the best implementation based upon other peoples experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace is a wrapper over `System.DirectoryServices`. The namespace contains classes covering the most common cases which programmers face, while working with AD. These classes are designed to perform a limited set of tasks in small to medium environments and have performance issues.

For example  `GroupPrincipal.Members` will load the entire group membership on first call, which may not be the desired behavior in enterprise environments where groups may contain 10-100k principals and range retrieval is the best option.

Using `System.DirectoryServices` or `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` allows you to manage resources (RAM, network traffic) that your process uses while communicating with AD.

`System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory` may be used in every environment, as the amount of data these classes return is quite small (e.g. Active Directory schema, sites, domain controllers)

Comment: I don't think I can use the Principal class directly because the methods contained within it are requiring the sAMAccountName, or some other input. So, I will need to use the DirectoryEntry.FindAll() method in order to identify all users and then I can go through the GroupPrincipal to find all Computer/User mappings and build intersection tables based off that data. However, I will need to determine how to go through the three objectCategories of User, Computer, and Groups. I will probably need to create a loop that sets the DirectorySearcher filter. Thanks.