# trying to search in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement to find AD user with pager field contains a string

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I'm trying to search using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` library in c#. The goal is to find an AD user with the pager field containing a string.

For example, if I have `.pager = "F1234b!@"` I need to find a user who's pager field contains "`1234`".

I can't figure out how to search the contents of the pager field in s.ds.am to contain a string.

Comment: Why `1234` and not `F1234b!@`?

Comment: @Joel, I assume Eric is providing a generic example where he wants to search both before and after a specific character string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the * character as a wildcard. For example, in the filter criteria for DirectoryEntry, you can use the following:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(pager=*1234*))
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679102(v=vs.85).aspx

Also, be careful using S.DS.AM. I know it provides a lot of useful functionality, but it is much slower than S.DS.AD.

[Active Directory: The Principal Class - S.DS.AM vs S.DS.AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759607/active-directory-the-principal-class-s-ds-am-vs-s-ds-ad)

**Update:**
Keep in mind that Microsoft introduced the following classes in the S.DS.AM namespace wrapper:

1. UserPrincipal
2. ComputerPrincipal
3. GroupPrincipal

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.aspx

Study the inheritance hierarchy and inspect the properties/attributes that are available -
 WYSWIG. If the attribute that you want to search for is not included then you will not be able to use S.DS.AM - you will need to use S.DS.AD.

The * wildcard still stands when searching for properties that are available within the Principal class that **contain** specific character strings.

A useful post when searching on available properties in S.DS.AM: [search by samaccountname with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635124/search-by-samaccountname-with-wildcards)

**Update 2:**

I ran across the following post on SO that might be useful for what you are trying to do: [How to get Active Directory Attributes not represented by the UserPrincipal class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929561/how-to-get-active-directory-attributes-not-represented-by-the-userprincipal-clas)

Comment: It's not the answer I'm looking for as it's not using s.ad.am, it's using the old school s.da.ad stuff, or if it is using .am, it's not a compete solution. As the answer will work with s.ds.ad, even though that' s not what I asked for I gave it an upvote for effort.
I'm deliberately trying to learn .AM after using AD. Thanks!

Comment: That won't work because pager is not a property of the UserPrincipal class. See the following weblink for properties that are made available within the UserPrincipal class. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you want to experiment with S.DS.AM, try using this method. Put a breakpoint at the return listPrincipal line and inspect each of the principal variables for what they contain.

```
private static List<Principal> GetPrincipalList (string strPropertyValue, string strDomainController)
        {
            List<Principal> listPrincipal = null;
            Principal principal = null;
            GroupPrincipal groupPrincipal = null;
            UserPrincipal userPrincipal = null;
            ComputerPrincipal computerPrincipal = null;
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> listPrincipalSearchResult = null; // Groups
            PrincipalContext principalContext = null;
            ContextType contextType;
            IdentityType identityType;

            try
            {
                // Setup a UserPrincipal list.
                listPrincipal = new List<Principal>();

                // Set the contextType to Domain because we are going through the AD directory store.
                contextType = ContextType.Domain;

                // Setup a domain context.
                principalContext = new PrincipalContext(contextType, strDomainController);

                // Setup the IdentityType. This is required, otherwise you will get a MultipleMatchesException error that says "Multiple principals contain a matching Identity."
                // This happens when you have two objects that AD thinks match whatever you're passing to UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContextDomain, strPropertyValue)
                // Use IdentityType.Guid because GUID is unique and never changes for a given object.                   
                identityType = IdentityType.Guid;

                // Find user.
                principal = Principal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, identityType, strPropertyValue);
                groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, identityType, strPropertyValue);
                userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, identityType, strPropertyValue);
                computerPrincipal = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, identityType, strPropertyValue);

                // Return the listPrincipal list.
                return listPrincipal;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Cleanup objects.
                listPrincipal = null;
                listPrincipalSearchResult = null;
                principalContext = null;
                groupPrincipal = null;
                userPrincipal = null;
                computerPrincipal = null;
            }
        }
```